# How to efficiently distribute large, incrementally updated sqlite database?

Tags: rsync, sqlite

## What is an efficient way to transfer deltas from a large sqlite database?

**Note**: this question is NOT about how to copy/distribute a "live" database. I.e. I am not concerned about corrupted journals, etc due to trying to copy while a write is in progress, because I am in full control of write times.

I have a large (~GB) sqlite database that is updated atomically by a scheduled process, and needs to be distributed to satellite locations.  Ideally the distribution can be either on-demand or scheduled (e.g. nightly), but scheduled only would be sufficient. Also ideally I would like to do this without running any kind of server process, or at minimum the process must be able to be run without elevated permissions.

My first instinct would be to use rsync for this. **Is rsync's delta-transfer algorithm efficient for sqlite databases?** Or does every write touch every block in the database file?  Does it matter if every change is insertion-only and never an update?

If rsync is inefficient (i.e. would end up transferring a significant fraction of the whole file each time), is there an out-of-the-box solution that would work better?

Comment: Perhaps distribute the updates themselves and redo the update on-sites?

Comment: Good question. It might be helpful to advise if CPU utilization is important. I don't have an answer for you, but look at https://rdiff-backup.net/ - As it uses the same algorithm as rsync - its not the solution to your problem but it should be able to help you work out the size of changes you will be dealing with.

Comment: Not sure this is doable; daily produce a "delta.db" which then gets distributed for addition to all copies of the database, e.g. a nightly update time.

Comment: @Hannu my big concern with that approach (other than not really knowing how to do that) is handling what happens if any of my receivers ever misses an update. Either they have to track their last update and we keep all the deltas until all receivers confirm receipt, or they have to redownload the whole thing